# css animation equivalent of the SVG/SMIL begin="scroll" (stc) events (no javascript)

Tags: css, svg, smil

I am converting svg/smil animations to use svg/css to take advantage of some better animation capabilities in css in a situation where there is **no javascript**.

Svg/Smil animations have a begin attribute which can be a named event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin) which allows interaction events like click, scroll, loaded, resize and so on to trigger the start of the animation (these listed are my most common required cases).

I've poured over a few css psuedoselector lists and found little, but there are always interesting tricks and hacks people have devised for capturing properties without javascript that I'm hoping someone might point me in a direction here. Of particular interst is if the svg element is in view (e.g. scrolled in / unoccluded / made visible), or if the document (or the svg) has been interacted with (clicked/tapped).

Comment: Are we talking about a specific situation where there is no JavaScript or just in general? If we talk general 98.93% of browsers support [ECMAScript 5](https://caniuse.com/es5) if it is not disabled. In the specific situation is there even support for the pseudo selectors you looked into ([CSS3 selectors](https://caniuse.com/css-sel3)) or animation etc. (like [CSS at-rule: `@keyframes`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_keyframes))? If you would like ideas for how to solve specific issues using CSS I think it would be a good idea to be more concrete -- like an example with SMIL scroll.

Comment: @chrwahl yes, there is no javascript. it is actively stripped out of the svg files, and there is no possibility of modifying the page hosting the svg file either. But smil and css animations are all unchanged..